# How do I choose an LCD controller board?

Tags: display, vga, lcd, controller

I have a Samsung SyncMaster SA350 which doesn't accept a VGA signal. It says "Check Signal Cable" while a VGA cable is plugged into it, so I assume there is something wrong with the LCD panel's controller board. I want to replace it if I can't find an easy fix.

1. How do I choose an LCD controller board that is compatible with the LCD panel?
2. Does each LCD only have one compatible controller board?
3. Where can I get LCD controller boards?

Some notes on what I am working with:

- Monitor: Samsung SyncMaster SA350
- LCD: LTM200KT08
- Controller: BN63-07709A
- Buttons panel: BN41-01635A

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find used ones on eBay. [Here's](http://dewangboard.com/2014_01/ZD100374.html) one for $18.  Generally, if it's not under warranty, your only option is to throw it away.